# Birthdays and wedding anniversary dates

Tags: contacts, 4.4-kitkat

I would like to know how to insert birthdays and wedding anniversary dates into contacts in my Android phone book.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what another answer implies, you can't add any field you want when you tap the <kbd>Add another field</kbd> button in the stock contact editor. You can only add from a pre-defined list of fields. Unfortunately, the stock contact viewer and editor don't support custom fields.

The good news is that you *can* add birthdays and anniversaries, though it's not immediately obvious how, because they're not independent fields, they're *categories* of the **Events** field.

In the `Add another field` box, check `Events` and tap <kbd>OK</kbd>. You'll then have an **Events** field that works much like the **Phone**, **Email**, and **Address** fields: you can add multiple entries (by tapping the green plus sign), and for each one you can select the category from the adjacent drop-down list.

More good news is that you can add custom *categories* for events, just as you can for addresses and phone numbers: select **Custom** from the drop-down list, and enter your custom category. In this case you won't need to do that, though, because **Birthday** and **Anniversary** happen to be the two pre-defined event categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom fields using the Gmail Contacts app in the browser.

From there, you can specify custom labels and values. Note, however, that these are not visible in the standard Android contacts viewer (People), even though they are synced to the Android phone.

For more details, see the [SoftWyer blog post](http://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/gmail-contacts-custom-fields-and-android/).

Answer (score -1):

Open your contact. Select "Edit" from the options menu. There you will see several fields for that specific contact. If you don't saw the birthday field there the there will a button in the end saying "And another field". Click that button and add whatever field you want.

By the way if your phonebook is synced with your google+ account. Then google has already fetched all the information of contacts including birthdays. You can see that in your google calender app.